# C#で天気情報(JSON)をasyncでとってきて、表示させたいのですが、処理が止まってしまいます。

Tags: c#, http

### 実現したいこと

非同期で気象庁の気象データを`Console.WriteLine()`で表示させたいです。

### 困っていること

`async`, `await`が止まってしまい、次のタスクへすすまず`Console.WriteLine()`で表示されなくなってしまいました。

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Weather
{
    public partial class Weather : Form
    {
        public Weather()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var url = "https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/forecast/data/forecast/010000.json";

            var task = WeatherAPI.FetchWeatherJsonData(url);

            task.Wait();

            var json = task.Result;

            foreach (var e in json)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        class WeatherAPI
        {
            public static async Task<JObject> FetchWeatherJsonData(string url)
            {
                var uri = new Uri(url);
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
                var json = JObject.Parse(data);
                return json;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 試しに`var json = JObject.Parse(data);`を外して生データをstringで受けて表示してみてはどうでしょう？ あるいは`task.Wait();`とか`task.Result;`とかを外して`json`を`await WeatherAPI.FetchWeatherJsonData(url);`で受けてみるとか？ こんな記事があります。[非同期処理、なにもわからない](https://www.kekyo.net/2021/02/24/7268)

Comment: コンストラクタでasyncタスクの結果待ちをしようとしているようですが、以下の質問同様のデッドロックが発生しているようで？ https://teratail.com/questions/48566

Comment: 上記コードの何がいけなかったかはわかりませんが、おそらくWait()、Resultを使っているのが悪かったようです。それらを削除して呼び出し側(コンストラクタ側)でWeatherAPI.FetchWeatherJsonData(url)をawaitをすれば動きました。

Comment: 典型的なデッドロックパターンのようです。https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6%E9%9D%9E%E5%90%8C%E6%9C%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

典型的なデッドロックパターンです。

microsoftによるベストプラクティスはこちらになります。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

これだけ読んでもよくわからないと思うので、補足説明を書きます。

1. await FooAsync()したとき、FooAsyncの中身は別スレッドで動作し、それが終了する時に元のコンテキスト（スレッドのグループのようなもの）に戻そうとします。
2. Windows Formアプリケーションにおいて、UIコンテキストには単一のスレッドしか存在しません。
3. task.Wait()を命令したのがUIコンテキストだった場合、このコンテキストはスレッドを1つしか持たずそれがWaitするため、事実上taskが完了するまで処理を受け付けなくなります。
4. taskの中でawait FooAsync()などされている場合、このFooAsync()が終わるときに元のコンテキストに戻そうとします。しかしそれがUIコンテキストだった場合、taskが完了するまで処理を受け付けないのでUIコンテキストに処理を返すことが出来ず、デッドロックします。